# How do I insert javascript immediately following the <head> opener, but only on the homepage? (Google Analytics AB Testing setup)

Tags: layout, index, conversion, head

I'm fairly new to Magento development.

How can I insert code immediately following  (not before ) on the index/home only?

I'm trying to insert some JavaScript for a Google Analytics Content Experiment Code (AB test). I was told that the code must be inserted immediately following the  tag. The *Miscellaneous Scripts* function will not work, because it inserts just before the , and after *getChildHtml('head')*.

I'm also not sure how I'd get the home page (CMS page) to reference my custom template, should I go the more obvious route.

All insights are welcomed!

Comment: Take a look at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11160/adding-javascript-to-head-in-certain-pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't already have a local.xml in your theme folder, just plop the below code in:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <cms_index_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/your_file.js</name></action>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index> 
</layout>
```

Add your your_file.js to your themes js folder. Here is a good boilerplate local.xml to reference: https://gist.github.com/Maksold/3956702